# Limiting the Number of Simultaneously Running Jenkins Jobs without Plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way to limit the number of concurrently running Jenkins jobs to two, where if a third job is executed, it should be put on hold until one of the running jobs is completed? I would like to achieve this without using any plugins.

I've tried implementing the following script in my Jenkinsfile, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. There is no error output, but the third job starts running instead of being put on hold.

```
stage('testing_stage') {
  environment {
    MAX_CONCURRENT_JOBS = 2
  }
  steps {
    script {
      // Get the current number of running builds for the current job
      def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
      def currentJob = jenkins.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
      def currentBuilds = currentJob.builds.findAll { it.isBuilding() }
      def runningBuilds = currentBuilds.size() - 1 // Exclude the current build itself

      // Wait until the number of running builds is below the limit
      while (runningBuilds >= MAX_CONCURRENT_JOBS) {
        println("Waiting for an available slot, ${runningBuilds} builds are currently running")
        sleep(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS') // Wait for 30 seconds before checking again

        // Update the number of running builds
        currentBuilds = currentJob.builds.findAll { it.isBuilding() }
        runningBuilds = currentBuilds.size() - 1
      }
    }
    // REST OF THE STAGE
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in this implementation? Is there a different approach I should consider to achieve the desired behavior of limiting the number of running Jenkins jobs to two, with the third job being put on hold until a slot becomes available? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If this is the only job you are running, you could set the number of executors on the Jenkins machine to 2, meaning that any other jobs will be put on hold.

Comment: @MB  i have other jobs